# Reducing button statelistdrawablecode

Tags: basic4android

I have this code working fine a few times in my project but was wondering the easiest way to allow it to be used for multiple buttons without repeating the code. For example - I have mybuttonBTN1 below and would like to add mybuttonBTN2, etc. - I've tried a few ways but always get weird results.

```
Dim buttonSLD As StateListDrawable
buttonSLD.Initialize
Dim buttonSTS(2) As Int
buttonSTS(0) = buttonSLD.State_Enabled
buttonSTS(1) = -buttonSLD.State_Pressed
buttonSLD.AddState2(buttonSTS, buttonENL)
Dim buttonSTS(1) As Int
buttonSTS(0) = bbuttonSLD.State_Pressed
buttonSLD.AddState2(bbuttonSTS, buttonPRS)
mybuttonBTN1.Background = buttonSLD
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like:

```
Sub SetStateDrawable (Btn As Button, Pressed As Drawable, Enabled As Drawable)
 Dim buttonSLD As StateListDrawable
 buttonSLD.Initialize
 Dim buttonSTS(2) As Int
 buttonSTS(0) = buttonSLD.State_Enabled
 buttonSTS(1) = -buttonSLD.State_Pressed
 buttonSLD.AddState2(buttonSTS, Pressed)
 Dim buttonSTS(1) As Int
 buttonSTS(0) = bbuttonSLD.State_Pressed
 buttonSLD.AddState2(bbuttonSTS, Enabled)
 Btn.Background = buttonSLD
End Sub

 SetStateDrawable(myButtonBTN1, buttonPRS, buttonENL)
```